# Setup a button to act as back button

Tags: android, back-button, android-button

I would like to setup a simple Alert View's OK button to act as the back button acts. What method should I use?

```
AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getContext());
                AlertDialog alert = alt_bld.create();
                alert.setTitle("Your score is: " + score);
                alert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
  //here would be the "back button's method"
}});
                alert.show();
```

Comment: Do you want to Finish Activity? Or do you want to dismiss Dailog? Please be clear

Comment: I would like to finish the current activity and to dismiss the Dialog, and to go back to the previous activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the finish method in order to destroy activity.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getContext());
                AlertDialog alert = alt_bld.create();
                alert.setTitle("Your score is: " + score);
                alert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 

                   // Enter you activity Name add call finish.

                   MyAcitivity.this.finish(); // Or MyAcitivity.this.onBackPressed()

}});
alert.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add:

```
NameOfYourContainingClass.this.onBackPressed();
```

Comment: this should be answer

Answer (score 0):

for that just this in your activity & call when button is clicked.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{ 
     super.onBackPressed();
};



    AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getContext());
                AlertDialog alert = alt_bld.create();
                alert.setTitle("Your score is: " + score);
                alert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
               onBackPressed();
}});
                alert.show();
```